# ExtJS4 - Is there an equivalent of xtype=tbtext for images in a Toolbar?

Tags: image, extjs4, toolbar

I'd like to be able to add an unadorned image to a toolbar (a company logo) that has no toolbar button behavior.  You can add text that way with an xtype of tbtext.  Is there something like tbimage?

If I try an image button, there are two problems - you get button behavior (mouse over, click, etc) and the image is cropped to 16x16.

I tried this:

```
xtype: 'button',
cls: 'logoImage'
```

But that only works in firefox and chrome, not in IE.

Is there a preferred way to add an image to a toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do to display a image on the toolbar:

```
{
    xtype: 'tbtext',
    text:'<div style="height:16px;width:48px;background: url(\'resources/img/logo_small.png\')" align="center"></div>'
}
```

Since, you are using tbtext, the image is not displayed as a button.